# Put Horizontal ScrollBar if image width is more than the width of richTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

When I add large image (width of the image is larger then width of Rich text Box), it doesn't showed in full size (i.e cropped). I can't scroll it horizontally. How should I enable horizontal scrolling or reduce image size automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ScrollViewer` to add a `Scrollbar` to any control:

```
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <Image Source="/Images/yourImage.png" Stretch="None" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

You didn't previously say that the image was in a `RichTextBox`... they have their own `ScrollViewer`s internally, so you can just do this:

```
<RichTextBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ... />
```

For future questions, please provide *all relevant information* with your question.

Comment: Hey Sheridan, thnx a lot for your response....i m checking with this and will let you know.

Comment: Why have you randomly added some code into that comment? Comments without words are pretty pointless really... you don't have to show me how a `ScrollViewer` works.

Comment: Hi Sheridan, I am usin following xaml code to add scroll in the richTextBox and mannually trying to paste some image (say from paint), but image is cropped from right instead of adding scroll                    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <RichTextBox Height="324" HorizontalAlignment="Left"      Margin="30,126,0,0" Name="rchTxtBoxBody" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="818" BorderBrush="LightBlue" />
</ScrollViewer>

Comment: Sorry Sheridan, i am new here, things are new for me.....so by mistake i pressed enter button.

Comment: Hey by using above code we can add scrollBar only on a grid but cant add on a richTextBox. Please suggest some idea to add scrollBar over richTextBox.

Comment: The code in my update *does* work, but perhaps you might want to set the value to `Visible` instead of `Auto`?